# Restringir capacidad máxima en un textfield

Tags: java, java-swing

estoy realizado un proyecto de la universidad, y tengo dudas en 2 textfield, mi duda es restringir la capacidad máxima de caracteres introducidos a 9 pero a la misma vez, si se digitaron 7 por ejemplo que diga una advertencia de que faltaron datos por introducir, se esta utilizando lo siguiente, hasta el momento el codigo funciona, pero es molesto que por cada vez que se introduce un numero salta una ventana:

```
    private void fieldTelefonoKeyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                       
    char a=evt.getKeyChar();// permitir ingresar solo números
    String verificaCantidadTelefono = fieldTelefono.getText();
    if(!Character.isDigit(a)){
        evt.consume();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Los números telefónicos costarricenses no permite letras.");
    }
    if (fieldTelefono.getText().length() == 8){ // limita cantidad de numeros ingresados
        evt.consume();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Los números telefónicos costarricenses solo tiene 8 dígitos.");
    }

    if(verificaCantidadTelefono.length() < 8)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Los números telefónicos costarricenses tienen 8 dígitos, usted ingreso: "+verificaCantidadTelefono);
    }
}
```

Comment: Te sugiero que revises esta publicación (inglés) -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3519151/how-to-limit-the-number-of-characters-in-jtextfield

Answer (score 0):

Mi sugerencia sería poner el código de validación en el evento de LostFocus y no en el de KeyTyped, pues efectivamente cada vez que se presione una tecla, va a saltarte el mensaje de alerta, en cambio, con el LostFocus, solo te avisará cuando terminen en el campo de texto y cambien a otro.

Quedaría de la siguiente forma:

```
//ASí quedaría tu codigo existente
private void fieldTelefonoKeyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                       
    char a=evt.getKeyChar();

    if(!Character.isDigit(a)){ //valida que solo sean numeros
        evt.consume();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Los números telefónicos costarricenses no permite letras.");
    }
}

//Esta parte la puedes agregar en el constructor de tu ventana ejemplo
java.awt.event.FocusListener myFocusListener = new java.awt.event.FocusListener() {

    public void focusLost(java.awt.event.FocusEvent focusEvent) {
        try {
            JTextField src = (JTextField)focusEvent.getSource();
            int cantidadDigitos = src.getText().length();

            if (src.getText().length() == 8){ // cantidad de numeros ingresados ok
                evt.consume();
            } else if(cantidadDigitos != 8) //valida que no sean mas ni menos que 8
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Los números telefónicos costarricenses tienen 8 dígitos, usted ingreso: " + cantidadDigitos);
            }
        } catch (ClassCastException ignored) {
            System.err.out("Error: " + ignored.toString());
        }
    }
}

fieldTelefono.addFocusListener(myFocusListener);

//... resto del código ...
```

No sé que tanto domines el lenguaje pero básicamente se está implementado una función que esté pendiente del evento de perdida de foco del campo. Cuando eso suceda, obtendrá cual fue el TextField que lo generó, y calculará la longitud del texto ingresado. Si la longitud es 8, permitirá seguir. En caso contrario, generará una alerta.